# Finding all words where the line number is the same in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has these columns
    df['Page', 'Word', 'LineNum'].

df =
    Idx Page    Word    LineNum
    0       1       Hello   1
    1       1       This    1
    2       1       is      2
    4       1       an      2
    5       2       example 1
    6       2       of      1
    7       2       words   1
    8       2       across  2
    9       2       multiple 2
    10      3       pages   1
    11      3       in      1
    12      3       the     1
    13      4       document 1
    14      4       which   1
    15      4       has     1
    16      4       split   1

This dataframe has been extracted from a csv file, and contains details about the document.

As you can imagine, several words appear in the same line (have the same value in LineNum), and a single page has several such lines.

This is what I want to do:

```
for( all the pages in the dataframe)
    if(  LineNum is the same )
        df['AllWordsInLine'] = add all the words in the df['Word'] column.
```

**Desired output**

1. LineDF['FullLine'] =
   Idx     FullLine
   0       Hello This
   1       is an
   2       example of words
   3       across multiple
   4       pages in the
   5       document which has split

I am just about 2 weeks into pandas, and I would much appreciate an expert's response.
thank you,
Venkat

Comment: `groupby` should work, show what you tried.

Comment: Hello Barmar, 
this is what I tried:
df['AllWordsInLine']  = df.groupby('Page')['Line']. I know this is not correct, but am not getting the right syntax.

Comment: Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your post correspondingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want all the words *across pages* for each line number. In other words, you want a mapping from line number to set of words.

You can achieve this by simply grouping by `LineNum` and aggregating to set. Here is a minimal example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Page':[0,0,0,1,1,1,2],
                   'Word':['a','b','a','d','e','d','g'],
                   'LineNum':[0,0,1,0,1,2,0]})

res = df.groupby('LineNum')['Word'].apply(set)

# LineNum
# 0    {b, g, a, d}
# 1          {a, e}
# 2             {d}
# Name: Word, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Page':[0,0,0,1,1,1,2],
               'Word':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'],
               'LineNum':[0,0,1,0,1,2,0]})

for line_page_tuple, subdf in df.groupby(['Page','LineNum']):
    print('Page:',line_page_tuple[0],', Line:',line_page_tuple[1],', All words in line:',
      subdf.Word.values)

# Page: 0 , Line: 0 , All words in line: ['a' 'b']
# Page: 0 , Line: 1 , All words in line: ['c']
# Page: 1 , Line: 0 , All words in line: ['d']
# Page: 1 , Line: 1 , All words in line: ['e']
# Page: 1 , Line: 2 , All words in line: ['f']
# Page: 2 , Line: 0 , All words in line: ['g']
```